# How to use constant values in Excel UDF?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I've been struggling to come up with a UDF in Excel. basically what I'm looking for is a function that would take 2 input parameters(constant) provided by a user, then the function would return one of the values pre-stored in an excel table somewhere. Here's what it would look like:

## month   Peak    off

1. January  320    176
2. February 320    128
3. March    368    252
4. April    352    128
5. May      305    320

The function would be like this: =Hours(February, Peak) then it would return February peak hours and so on.

I appreciate all the help. Thanks a lot

EDIT: Code added as comment

```
Public Function calculateHours(ByVal mo As Variant, ByVal period As Variant) As Integer    
 Dim tablette As Range 
 Set tablette = Worksheets("Hours").Range("U4:V15") 
 Set valueRange = Worksheets("Hours").Range("U4:U15") 
 period = "peak" 
 For Each ref In valueRange 
   mo = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ref, tablette, 1, 0) 
 Next 
 ref calculateHours = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mo, tablette, 2, False) 
End Function
```

When I try to use this function such in =calculateHours(january, peak) I only get the last value from table regardless what the parameters are

Comment: In your UDF use `Application.Vlookup()` to perform the lookup against your table of values.

Comment: You are asking for a full function based on some design you would like to create. Please read up some beginner's material on VBA functions, e.g. Chip Pearson's site or simple examples on MSDN and try to create your function. Then, if it gives a specific error, do post it here

Comment: Instead of a UDF, you could use a VLOOKUP, like so (assuming the data is kept in sheet 'Hours' in range A1:C13 with row 1 being the header row, and the current inputs are A1 for the month and B1 for peak/off): `=VLOOKUP(A1,Hours!$A$2:$C$13,IF(B1="peak",2,3),FALSE)`

Comment: If it's pre-stored in a table, then you just use VLOOKUP.  No need for a UDF.

Comment: I have a partially working solution. As both of you suggested, I know I can lose VLookup, but in this particular case I want to create a UDF because the table is huge and is shared among workbook users. That's why I want to use meaningful parameters such as (month, peak)

Comment: Sorry guys, I should've clarified the problem a bit more. The reason why I need a UDF is because I want to be able to use those pre-stored values in other workbooks without having to open this particular one which stores these values. Thanks

Comment: Please post your partially working solution so that people don't recreate your efforts.

Comment: if you know how to use Vlookup on a spreadsheet, you can simply use `WorksheetFunction.VLookup()` in VBA. That way you can maintain your spreadsheet's logic with minimal changes

Comment: Public Function calculateHours(ByVal mo As Variant, ByVal period As Variant) As Integer

   Dim tablette As Range
   Set tablette = Worksheets("Hours").Range("U4:V15")
   Set valueRange = Worksheets("Hours").Range("U4:U15")
   period = "peak"
   For Each ref In valueRange
       mo = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ref, tablette, 1, 0)
   Next ref
       calculateHours = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mo, tablette, 2, False)
End Function When I try to use this function such in =calculateHours(january, peak) I only get the last value from table regardless what the parameters are

Comment: @user3813620 Don't use comment section to post code. Just edit your question as I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function ReturnVale(period As String, MinMax As String) As Variant
    months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    Off = Array(330, 347, 366, 393, 307, 353, 310, 347, 332, 307, 400, 333)
    Peak = Array(399, 428, 440, 446, 366, 431, 370, 413, 389, 364, 470, 421)
    For i = LBound(months) To UBound(months)
        If period = months(i) Then
            GoTo done
        End If
    Next i
    ReturnVale = "NOT FOUND"
    Exit Function
done:
    If MinMax = "Peak" Then
        ReturnVale = Peak(i)
    Else
        ReturnVale = Off(i)
    End If
End Function
```

Naturally you would modify the **Array()** statements to match your requirements.

Comment: I was going to write a similar answer. One thing I would change: use `period = Application.Match(period, months, FALSE)` rather than loop through explicitly. This will return a `1` if the match is the first match - so you need `Option Base 1` or make sure that your lookup in `Peak` or `Off` has the correct offset...

Comment: @Gary's Student, You are a life saver! That's exactly what I was looking for. I will customize it and build more arrays to accommodate my needs. Thanks a lot I greatly appreciate it.